# open multiple file and write content using loop using bash

Tags: bash

I have written a script to create multiple files with content

```
            #!/bin/bash
            for i in {1..3}
               do 
                  for j in {2..5}
                    do cat > file$i.in <<EOF
                      strip.pro.prm
                      $j/$i.xyz

                      ref 1.xyz
                      image origin center
                      out combined$i.top 
                      EOF
                    done
               done
```

I want this  `$j/$i.xyz` to be printed using the second loop to give me output in the file as

```
 1/1.xyz
 2/2.xyz
 3/3.xyz
```

but this script writes only the last one.

Comment: Actually your script does write all of them, it just overwrites the same file everytime. You can see this happening if you append to `file$i.in` instead of overwriting it. `do cat >> file$i.in <<EOF`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but then it also write strip.pro.prm and the last three lines multiple times in the file. I want only $j/$i.xyz to go through the loop and the other lines to be written as it is in the file.